# Texts without sub-pixel rendering in Firefox and its variants (Librewolf, Tor, etc) look blurry in LCD monitors

Tags: firefox, css, about-config, font-smoothing

This problem occurs for **tabs** font as well as font in **Library manager**:

[image]

Can you test and confirm it? Is there any solution? Can I force enable **sub-pixel rendering**?

Things I tried before:

1. disabling **Fingerprinting**.
2. changing these settings below in `about:config`:

   `gfx.font_rendering.cleartype_params.rendering_mode`

   `gfx.font_rendering.cleartype_params.force_gdi_classic_for_families`

   `gfx.font_rendering.cleartype_params.force_gdi_classic_max_size`

   `gfx.font_rendering.directwrite.use_gdi_table_loading`

   `gfx.webrender.force-disabled`
3. going into **Troubleshoot Mode**.

It has been reported before:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1707465

**Update:**
I found that disabling mask-image in tabs fixed tabs font, here's what I used in userchrome.css:

```
/* delete tab text fading / gradient effect (also fix lcd Subpixel rendering)*/
.tab-label-container[textoverflow]:not([pinned]) {mask-image: unset !important;}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue since Firefox 90: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1724057

Comment: Thanks for the info, anyway I managed to fix the tabs font by disabling mask-image in userchrome.css